# Vue CLI / Typescript based project no longer builds or runs Mocha tests

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have Vue 2 project scaffolded from Vue CLi that is throwing dozens of errors. It complies fine for developing but running unit tests or building for production it all goes wrong.

Below is a sample of the errors, Package.json file,  vue.config.js

### Here is an example of some the errors:

#### These have to do with using Typescript `?.`

```
    error  in ./tests/unit/store/programme/programme/getters.spec.ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (24:38)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     it('returns a Programme with the id of `selectedProgrammeId`', function () {
|       state.programmes.selectedProgrammeId = programmeCollection[2]._id;
>       expect(getters.programme(state)?._id).to.eq(programmeCollection[2]._id);
|     });
|   });

 @ ./node_modules/mochapack/lib/entry.js 7:2895-2975
```

#### Compiling Vuetify

````
 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSwitch/VSwitch.sass

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import './_variables.scss'
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  Users/davidclare/Documents/strata%202/admin-2-spa/node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSwitch/VSwitch.sass 1:9  root stylesheet

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VSwitch/VSwitch.sass 4:14-209
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSwitch/VSwitch.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSwitch/index.js
 @ ./src/views/Programme/Module/Edit.dialog.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--15-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Programme/Module/Module.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/views/Programme/Module/Module.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/views/Programme/Module/Module.vue
 @ ./tests/unit/programme/module/journalItemsButton.spec.ts
 @ ./node_modules/mochapack/lib/entry.js```

## Package.json

    {
      "name": "2-spa",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vue-cli-service serve --mode Local",
        "prep": "npm run audit; npm run test:unit; npm run lint; npm run build:dev",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --mode development",
        "audit": "npm audit --audit-level=moderate --production",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "build:dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode Development",
        "build:test": "vue-cli-service build --mode Test",
        "build:prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode Production"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.12.1",
        "@types/auth0-js": "^9.14.0",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
        "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
        "apollo-link-batch-http": "^1.2.14",
        "array-move": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "graphql": "^15.3.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "logrocket": "^1.0.13",
        "logrocket-vuex": "0.0.3",
        "opossum": "^5.1.3",
        "retry-axios": "^2.4.0",
        "simplemde-theme-base": "^0.2.1",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-apollo": "^3.0.4",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-fragment": "^1.5.1",
        "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.5",
        "vue-simplemde": "^1.1.2",
        "vue-toasted": "^1.1.28",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.1",
        "vuetify": "^2.3.12",
        "vuex": "^3.5.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "^4.2.12",
        "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
        "@types/opossum": "^4.1.1",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
        "@types/vue-markdown": "^2.2.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.3.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.1.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "1.1.0",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint": "^7.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-graphql": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.1",
        "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
        "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "prettier": "2.2.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.11",
        "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
        "typescript": "~4.0.3",
        "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "~0.22.2",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0"
      }
    }


## vue.config.js
````

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  lintOnSave: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    apollo: { lintGQL: true },
  },
};
```

```
vue info

    Environment Info:
    
      System:
        OS: macOS 10.15.7
        CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Binaries:
        Node: 14.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node
        Yarn: Not Found
        npm: 7.18.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm
      Browsers:
        Chrome: 91.0.4472.114
        Edge: Not Found
        Firefox: 89.0.1
        Safari: 14.1.1
      npmPackages:
        @types/vue-markdown: ^2.2.1 => 2.2.1 
        @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.0.0 
        @vue/babel-helper-vue-transform-on:  1.0.0-rc.2 
        @vue/babel-plugin-jsx:  1.0.0-rc.3 
        @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.1.2 
        @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.5.6 
        @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.1.2 
        @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.1.2 
        @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.1.2 
        @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.1.2 
        @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.1.2 
        @vue/cli-overlay:  4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-router: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-typescript: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-plugin-vuex: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-service: ~4.5.6 => 4.5.6 
        @vue/cli-shared-utils:  4.5.6 
        @vue/compiler-core:  3.0.5 
        @vue/compiler-dom:  3.0.5 
        @vue/compiler-sfc:  3.0.5 
        @vue/compiler-ssr:  3.0.5 
        @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.2.0 
        @vue/eslint-config-prettier: ^6.0.0 => 6.0.0 
        @vue/eslint-config-typescript: ^5.1.0 => 7.0.0 
        @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.2 
        @vue/shared:  3.0.5 
        @vue/test-utils: 1.1.0 => 1.1.0 
        @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0 
        eslint-plugin-vue: ^7.0.1 => 7.11.1 
        logrocket-vuex: 0.0.3 => 0.0.3 
        typescript: ~4.0.3 => 4.0.3 
        vue: ^2.6.12 => 2.6.12 
        vue-apollo: ^3.0.4 => 3.0.4 
        vue-chartjs: ^3.5.1 => 3.5.1 
        vue-cli-plugin-apollo: ~0.22.2 => 0.22.2 
        vue-cli-plugin-vuetify: ~2.0.7 => 2.0.7 
        vue-eslint-parser:  7.6.0 
        vue-fragment: ^1.5.1 => 1.5.1 
        vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.4 
        vue-loader:  15.9.3 (16.1.2)
        vue-markdown: ^2.2.4 => 2.2.4 
        vue-router: ^3.4.5 => 3.4.5 
        vue-simplemde: ^1.1.2 => 1.1.2 
        vue-style-loader:  4.1.2 
        vue-template-compiler: ^2.6.12 => 2.6.12 
        vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1 
        vue-toasted: ^1.1.28 => 1.1.28 
        vuedraggable: ^2.24.1 => 2.24.1 
        vuetify: ^2.3.12 => 2.3.12 
        vuetify-loader: ^1.6.0 => 1.6.0 
        vuex: ^3.5.1 => 3.5.1 
      npmGlobalPackages:
        @vue/cli: 4.5.13
```

Comment: I believe this is related: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6833

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by the use of the Javascript [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). This is a feature supported in es2020 and above, and apparently the default Babel configuration for Vuejs will not know how to deal with it.

I found a [suggestion in a related issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6833#issuecomment-977330146) in the Vuejs repo to target 'es2019' in tsconfig.json, and that fixed the issue for me:

```
  # tsconfig.json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2019",
      ...  
    }
  }
```

Comment: did not solve the problem for me, unfortunately